# Path name with accented character and space

Tags: filesystem

My question is in the `smb.conf` can I specify a path containing an accented character and space such as `path = /home/Senis/Serveur/Batiment/BÂTIMENT-ICI 2020/D20-44 Ibalt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The accented character should not be an issue. Use `"`'s (double quotes) for the space.

```
path = "/home/Senis/Serveur/Batiment/BÂTIMENT-ICI 2020/D20-44 Ibalt"
```

Probably this will work too:

```
path = /home/Senis/Serveur/Batiment/BÂTIMENT-ICI%202020/D20-44%20Ibalt
```

Comment: should I use %20 to replace all space,  like between ICI and 2020  . so the complete path should be "path = /home/Senis/Serveur/Batiment/BÂTIMENT-ICI%202020/D20-44%20Ibalt

Comment: thank you with the "" works

Comment: the " method will work and yes %20 every space